# Updating an arraylist if the object exists

Tags: android, arraylist

Need some help on how to update a list. I've got a class which defines the object with string name, string status, float lat and float long.

Every time a player moves a server sends me an asynchronous message whit these variables, the only thing changing can be status lat and long which are the ones I want to "overwrite". The name is unique so I'm guessing I have to search based on that as that's the thing never changing. I want to update the existing object to prevent one player from occurring more then once.

My (non functional) code so far:

```
    if(players.size()==0){ ///// 1.
                        Player p  = new Player();
                        p.name = split[2];
                        p.status = split[3];
                        p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
                        p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);
                        players.add(p);
                    }//This works


                    else{ ///// 2.
                    for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){ ///// 3.
                        if(players.get(i).name.equals(split[2])){
                            Player p  = new Player();
                            p.name = split[2];
                            p.status = split[3];
                            p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
                            p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);
                            players.add(p);
                            players.add(i, p);
                        }
                        else{ ///// 4.
                            Player p  = new Player();
                            p.name = split[2];
                            p.status = split[3];
                            p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
                            p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);
                            players.add(p);
                        }
                    }//This doesnt
                    }
```

It's probably something obvious but I don't really know how to search and replace an object. The functionality I'm after is:

1. Check if the list is empty in which case there can't be a player in it so just add one.
2. If the list exists loop through it and look for the name of the objects.
3. If the name exists, simply create the same player again but with its update values at the same index.
4. The list exists but the name isn't found so just add the player.

My code so far puts me in an never ending loop I'm guessing since the app stops responding. The split variable is one word split up from the asynchronous call which is the name, this I've checked by printing it.

Comment: Sounds like a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to me...

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
players.add(p);
players.add(i, p);
```

use

```
players.set(i, p)
```

Comment: Well this appends its or overwrites the existing one but it also adds a new player at the end of the arraylist

Comment: After some more testing, this works with just one object in the list. It overwrites it but if I add a second object it starts adding the previous existing one to the end of the arraylist. It seemd like its doing it like this: only one exists overwrite, 2 objects exist, does the first match, no and add a new, it now loops over two objects at the second object the first objects name doesnt match so it adds a new one. How do I prevent this? If a match has been found it needs to be taken out of the loop somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Well I finally took dmons advice and made a hashmap, I have no idea if its good practice but it does seem to work with this instead:

```
    if(players.size()==0){
                        Player p = new Player();
                        p.name = split[2];
                        p.status = split[3];
                        p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
                        p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);
                        players.add(p);
                        hash.put(split[2], p);
                    }
                    else{
                        Player p = new Player();
                        p.name = split[2];
                        p.status = split[3];
                        p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
                        p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);
                        players.add(p);
                        hash.put(split[2], p);
                        }
```

With the hashmap being instantiated in oncreate and takes a string key which is the name and a Player object in it.

Comment: This is a good example of using a HashMap. However, for updating a value in an ArrayList, it is better to use indexOf instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **indexOf** to know if the p object exist inside players. That will return -1 if don't exist or the position in case p object exist inside players.

```
    Player p  = new Player();
    p.name = split[2];
    p.status = split[3];
    p._lat = Float.valueOf(split[4]);
    p._long = Float.valueOf(split[5]);

    if(players.size()==0){
        players.add(p);
    }
    else{
        int index=players.indexOf(p);
        if (index==-1){
            players.add(p);
        }
        else{
            players.set(index,p);
        }
    }
```

the trick is add inside your Player class this method that override the equal method used on indexOf. This way, you can set the necessary conditions for two Player objects to be equal (only the name in your case).

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (o.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
        String a = this.name;
        String b = ((Player) o).name;
        return a.equalsIgnoreCase(b);
    }
    return false;
}
```