# Update an arraylist if the object exists on id

Tags: java

I need to update an ArrayList if object exists based on id in the object.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details

Comment: Where *is* this *object*? Is it in the ArrayList? And how do you want to update the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating an arraylist if the object exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659924/updating-an-arraylist-if-the-object-exists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update specific object items inside array list java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993540/update-specific-object-items-inside-array-list-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arraylist have a `mArrayList.contains()` method and than you can get the element index by looping and update item if you are requesting to update in the ArrayList and not somewhere else :

```
mArrayList.set(yourdesiredIndexOfTypeInt , desiredValueOrObject);
```

Comment: Note: `contains()` ["returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), so your object will need to implement `equals()` based on the `id` field for this to work.